# Understanding ASP.NET MVC Routes reg

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've created a system in MVC  using the NerdDinner tutorial as a base to work off.

Everything was working fine until I used single action methods such as

Here is the global.asax.cs

```
  routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "mysample", id=UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

which routes to

```
http:localhost/Home/mysample
```

i just want to create routes which has more than one action in the sense

```
http:localhost/<controller>/<action>/<params>
ex: localhost/mycontroller/myaction/details/myname
```

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

update 1:

i have writen router like this as

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "myname",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{details}/{myname}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "mycontroller", action = "myaction", details= "details", myname= "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

and retried the value with following syntax as

```
String name=RouteData.Values["myname"].ToString();
```

it works fine .

but even though the url called as

```
localhost/mycontroller/myaction/details
```

its being routed to that controller and error is being thrown as null reference...

how to avoid it?

Comment: Do you want multiple params in your route or action chaining?

Comment: @freshbm action chaining

Comment: You can't do that. You can have multiple parameters for one route, but you can't have multiple action chained via MVC routes. This is example of action chaining, but it's not trivial. http://jwbs-blog.blogspot.com/2009/08/chaining-aspnet-mvc-actions.html What do you want to do?

Comment: @freshbm check my updates

Comment: null reference from what?

Comment: @WannaCSharp since i am not passing "myname" params and getting that value inside controller..

Comment: Can you post us your controller code, I don't get what are you trying to achieve...

Answer (score 1):

You can't define multiple actions in one MVC route.
In MVC routing configuration is used for mapping your Controlers and Actions to user friendly routes and:

> 1. Keep URLs clean
> 2. Keep URLs discoverable by end-users
> 3. Avoid Database IDs in URL

Understanding default route config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default", // Route name
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "mysample", id=UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

> The "routeTemplate" property on the Route class defines the Url
>   matching rule that should be used to evaluate if a route rule applies
>   to a particular incoming request.
>
> The "defaults" property on the Route class defines a dictionary of
>   default values to use in the event that the incoming URL doesn't
>   include one of the parameter values specified.

Default route will map all requests, because it has defined default values for every property in routeTemplate, {} means that property is variable, if you not provide value for that param in URL, it will try to take default value if you provide it. In default route it has defined defaults for controller, action and id param is optional. That means if you have route like this:

> .../Account/Login

It will take you to *Account* controller, *Login* action and because you didn't specified prop and it is defined as optional it will work.

> .../Home

This will also work, and it will take you to *Home* contoller and *mysample* action

When you define custom route, like you did:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "myname",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{details}/{myname}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "mycontroller", action = "myaction", details= "details", myname= "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

You didn't specified myname as optional and you didn't specified it your route, that means that your URL: **localhost/mycontroller/myaction/details** wan't be handled by your custom route myname. It will be handled by default route. And when you try to access your myname param in controller it wan't be there and you will get null reference error. If you want to specifie default value of your parameter if not present in url you need to do that in your controller. For example:

```
public class MyController : Controller
    {
         public ActionResult MyAction(string details = "details", string myname = "") 
         {
                ...
```

and change your custom route to:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                    "myname",                                              // Route name
                    "{controller}/{action}/{details}/{myname}",                           // URL with parameters
                    new { controller = "mycontroller", action = "myaction", details= UrlParameter.Optional, myname= UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
                );
```

But you can define only one controller and only one action, rest of the *routeTemplate* are parameters.

You can't define two action in one route. It make no sense.